Dataset Problem "You Have a usable connection already"
I'm using VS 19 Professional.
I'm having problems with my Data Set. Until one day it worked normally but that's no longer the case. I'm using mysql-connector-net-6.9.8 and mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.10.
However, for some time now I've been facing this annoying problem, and I'm not able to solve it. I've already reinstalled VS19 on other machines, and I don't know what else to do.
This is a new project. But I have this same problem in old projects (Those that are already created work perfectly. But if I try to create a new one it doesn't work.)
enter image description here
I can even create the dataset, but when trying to create a query I receive this error:
enter image description here
And the problem is not related to any IP or password error or anything. To the database. It's working perfectly.
I changed the DLL and reinstalled VS19 on my DISK C. I moved the MySql installation folder (where mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.10 and mysql-connector-net-6.9.8 are located) to disk D. Now I did the tests on a VM, I did it on systems that already worked. And it's not working.
